# Can I have a Django model that has a foreign key reference to itself?

Tags: django, django-models

Okay, how would I do this?

```
class Example(models.Model):
  parent_example = models.ForeignKey(Example)
```

I want to have a model have a foreign key reference to itself.  When I try to create this I get a django validation error that Example is not yet defined.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

You should use

```
models.ForeignKey('self')
```

as mentioned [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey).

Answer (score 21):

Yes, just do this:

```
class Example(models.Model):
  parent_example = models.ForeignKey('self')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using quotes too:

```
class Example(models.Model):
    parent_example = models.ForeignKey('Example')
```