# Django models: One to one relationship between objects of the same model class

Tags: django, django-models, python-2.7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I have a Django model that has a foreign key reference to itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534700/can-i-have-a-django-model-that-has-a-foreign-key-reference-to-itself)

I want to implement a simple folder-file like structure in my Django app. So I have a model for storing folders, but I also would like to store relation between this folder and parent folder. The simplified version of model would look like following:

```
class mFolder(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    parentFolder = models.ForeignKey(mFolder, unique=False, related_name="childrenFolders")
```

However this is not possible, beacause mFolder is not declared yet.

Is there any simple solution for that problem?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: It's not one-to-one, it's one-to-many.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Should be 'self':

```
parentFolder = models.ForeignKey('self', unique=False, related_name="childrenFolders")
```

Comment: Works great, sorry for lame question. Cheers!