# Best way to store category and subcategories of an item in Django models

Tags: python, django, database, models

I want to store something like an Apple which will be stored as "Tree Fruit - Apple - Fuji - Organic" while there will be some items with more categories like Wheat which is "Cereal Grain - Wheat - Soft White Winter - Stephens - Organic".

```
class Item(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None ,blank=True) #Cereal Grain
    commodity = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None ,blank=True) #Wheat
    cl = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None ,blank=True) #Soft White Winter
    variety = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None ,blank=True) #Stephens
    market = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None ,blank=True) #Organic

    def __str__(self):
        return u"%s" % (self.user)



class Shorten_Item(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None ,blank=True) #Tree Fruit
    commodity = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None ,blank=True) #Apple
    variety = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None ,blank=True) #Fuji
    market = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None ,blank=True) #Organic


    def __str__(self):
        return u"%s" % (self.user)
```

There will cost items associated reference to those tables.

```
class User_Variable_Items(models.Model):

    #variety = models.ForeignKey(User_Variety)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100,default=None ,blank=True)
    sub_category = models.CharField(max_length=100,default=None ,blank=True)
    item = models.CharField(max_length=100,default=None ,blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20,decimal_places=2,default=None ,blank=True)
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=100,default=None ,blank=True)
    quantity = models.FloatField(default=0,blank=True)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20,decimal_places=2,default=None ,blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = _("User_Variable_Items")

class User_Fixed_Items(models.Model):

    #variety = models.ForeignKey(User_Variety)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100,default=None ,blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20,decimal_places=2,default=None ,blank=True)
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=100,default=None ,blank=True)
    quantity = models.FloatField(default=0,blank=True)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20,decimal_places=2,default=None ,blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = _("User_Fixed_Items")
```

What would be the best way to have the `User_Variable_Cost_Items` and `User_Fixed_Cost_items` to reference to one of the table above (not both)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can reorganize your models, you can make use of models inheritance (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance)

Your `Item` model could have been a sub class of `Shorten_Item`, given that it only contains one extra field, the `cl = CharField()`

You can keep `Shorten_Item` as it is, then make `Item` inherit from that model:

```
class Item(Shorten_Item):
    cl = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None ,blank=True)
```

Now in your other class,

```
class User_Variable_Items(models.Model):

    ...
    # Add a foreign key to the base Item class
    # Which by inheritance can contain both keys from Shorten_Item and Item
    item = ForeignKey('Shorten_Item')
```

When you retrieve the ID of the Shorten_Item, use your business logic to determine if you want to use it as `Shorten_Item` or `Item` (by downcasting it to `Item` when needed)

If you cannot reorganize your models to benefit from inheritance, your only solution might be to use an `item_id = IntegerField()` as a "foreign key" that will be able to point to any table, and you'll have to write some more queries yourself

Answer (score 5):

I think what you are trying to do is:

To have a type of item, from a certain category, that can be on a inheritance hierarchy. Itens can have diferent types and make diferent things, this sounds like a inheritance structure (e.g Item > PriceFixedItem and Item > VariablePriceItem).

On this way you can try to compose a data structure to store and recover the data from a database. Can you try to do something like this:

Create a Model that refers to himself, to make a tree of categories, can be anything like:

```
class Category(models.Model):
     parent = models.ForeignKey('self') # Here category will refer to it self
     name = models.CharField()
```

Now your items can refer to only one category, and you can turn the things here more dynamics:

```
 class Item(models.Model):
     category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
     name = models.CharField()
     price = models.FloatField()
```

We are going now to have different types of items:

```
class FixedPriceItem(Item):
    pass

class VariablePriceItem(Item):
    price_tax = models.FloatField()
```

The best for now is that how we have this structure, Django can solve the problems you have, but how? That's simple, look this:

```
class UserItem(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
```

From now you have one single object type to manage user items, that's very good to maintain. The most important thing i can see here is that you are trying to solve this problem on a database's structure, but when you are programming over an ORM framework like on Django, you don't have to care too much about you database structure, you need to solve your problems on the programming language, Python on this case, so its simple to solve that problem using OO concepts, like this one. Other important thing is a concept that you have to keep in mind for all your life: The object who have the data, is the object who cares about the data. If you implement this your control logic on the wrong place, you will have to write much more, and cry much more, in this example, you have to let the Item objects to care about like they will present, calculate or store his data. Don't try to implement the controls on User's classes, this will be very valuable when you will have another type of item, and you will need to put one more `if` to verify if uses this item like this or that.

Comment: To have a model with a foreign key referring to itself use `models.ForeignKey('self')`...see the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) and this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534700/can-i-have-a-django-model-that-has-a-foreign-key-reference-to-itself)

Comment: Just updated, thanks. I knew about `'self'`, it was just a lack.