# Django relative_name issues on model Inheritance

Tags: django, django-models, inheritance, django-rest-framework, foreign-keys

I have an issus with inheritance on models and reverse relations.

Here my models :

```
class A(B):
  designation = CharField()

class B ():
  owner = ForeignKey(A, null=True, blank=True, related_name='sites')
  name = CharField()
  street1 = CharField()

class C():
  name = CharField()
  relation_a = ForeignKey(A, related_name='all_elements', null=True, blank=True)
  relation_b = ForeignKey(B, related_name='elements', null=True, blank=True)
```

Firstly my model A inherits from the model B for get all address informations.Model A can have several sites(B)

I have an other model C with foreign key to model A and another to model B.

For each element B I want get all elements. This work fine:

```
for b in B.objects.all():
   print(b.elements.all())
```

For get all elements link to A is work:
 `print(A.all_elements.all())`

But I can't get just the element C linked to A by the relation_b

`print(A.elements.all())`

I got an empty list. If I want only this element I need to pass by B models
`B.objects.get(id=A.id).elements.all()`

This is the first issues.

Secondly, my main problem is with serializer.

My serializer :

```
A_Serializer(B_Serializer):
    class Meta:
        model = A
        fields = [
            'designation',
            'street1',
            'site',
            'all_elements',
            'elements',
        ]
        expandable_fields = {
            'sites': (B_Serializer, {'many'=True}
            'all_elements': (C_Serializer,{'many':True}),
            'elements': (C_Serializer,{'many':True}),
        }
```

In DRF I can expend the all_elements in serializer A. I can expain the elements in serialier B
But I can't expaind the element in serializer A.

I try to use a SerializerMethodField in A_serializer for elements but I loose the expand feature for elements.

I'm stuck here.

How can I get from my object A his elements expandable. I need from this object A expand his element B and for each element B expand there elements C.

Thank you for yours times.

Comment: Can you maybe quickly describe why you want to have model C? You probably gave a minimal example and that's why the info is lost. Also: Why the inheritance of model B from A? Do you want model A have a set of linked B models plus having model A the model fields of B itself? Long story short: Why is a "normal" setup of model A and model B not sufficient for you?

Comment: I need model C for got a list of equipement for earch Model B(sites). I need also the relation to model A(company) for got all equipements of all company. But model A (maint site )can have his own equipements. The inheitance is for avoid repet fields, like address or name. Model A is a company with several sites (Model B), but A can be a site too.  By 'normal' you say without inherance ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an approach with an abstract model can help you? It would look like this more or less:

```py
class MyAbstractModel(models.Model):
    """
    An abstract base class with all the fields you
    you need in other models
    """
    name = CharField()
    street1 = CharField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class A(MyAbstractModel):
    owner = ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='sites')
    designation = CharField()

class B (MyAbstractModel):
    owner = ForeignKey(A, null=True, blank=True, related_name='sites')

class C():
    name = CharField()
    relation_a = ForeignKey(A, related_name='all_elements', null=True, blank=True)
    relation_b = ForeignKey(B, related_name='elements', null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the proposition. I have a question about the foreign key in the model Abstract. There is no problem to create a link to Model A ? 
I will make some test with than .Thanks

Comment: I think you are correct, it could give problems (I haven't tested it in the past). I just modified my answer based on [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534700/can-i-have-a-django-model-that-has-a-foreign-key-reference-to-itself). Hope it helps.